# Is it possible in SQL Server to convert the type of a field based on the content of another field?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a table, DD, which is a data dictionary, with fields (say):

```
ColumnID (longint PK), ColumnName (varchar), Datatype (varchar)
```

I have another table, V, where I have sets of records in the form:

```
ColumnID (longint FK), ColumnValue (varchar)
```

I want to be able to convert sets of records from V into another table, Results, where each field will be translated based on the *value* of DD.Datatype, so that the destination table might be (say):

```
ColumnID (longint FK), ColumnValue (datetime)
```

To be able to do this, ISTM that I need to be able to do something like

```
CONVERT(value of DD.Datatype, V.ColumnValue)
```

Can anyone give me any clues on whether this is even possible, and if so what the syntax would be? My google-fu has proved inadequate to find anything relevant

Comment: Any *particular* query always produces result sets with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and their *types*. You certainly can't have what seems to be implied in your question here - a result set with, potentially, each *row* having a column containing values of different types.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What I'm looking to do is create a de-normalised view of a parent table and a set of records in a child table. 

So, using my original names, I'd have 1 record in parent table and a number of records in *V* which are attributes of that parent; my output would be a table *Results* which contained the fields from parent *and* 1 field from each record in *V* which was a child of the parent record

Comment: Perhaps if you can provide details about the source data and the desired output we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Let me give a bit of context. What I'm trying to do is create a design which is agnostic to the data being fed into it. By which I mean, there are a number of data sets of various "shapes" (different combinations of columns) which can be loaded into this database. Rather than creating table(s) with a superset of all the columns, what I want to do is create 1 parent record *for each record* of the incoming data, and 1 child record for *each column of each record* of the incoming data.

Comment: The incoming data is all CSV, so effectively text. However, to *use* the data, I need to type-convert some of it, based on a definition of what the type of source column is supposed to be; the definition is held in my data dictionary which is another table.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do:
[img]http://i.imgur.com/GpqmNBH.png

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with dynamic sql, certainly.  As long as you are aware of the limitation that the datatype is a property of the COLUMN in the resultset, and not each cell in the resultset.   So all the rows in a given column must have the same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish something like `CONVERT(value of DD.Datatype, V.ColumnValue)` in SQL is with dynamic SQL.  That has it's own problems, such as basically needing to use stored procedures to keep queries efficient.

Alternately, you could fetch the datatype metadata with one query, construct a new query in your application, and then query the database again.  Assuming you're using SQL Server 2012+, you could also try using `TRY_CAST()` or `TRY_CONVERT()`, and writing your query like:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(value as VARCHAR(2)) FieldName
FROM table 
WHERE datatype = 'VARCHAR' AND datalength = 2
```

But, again, you've got to know what the valid types are; you can't determine that dynamically with SQL without dynamic SQL.  Variables and parameters are not allowed to be used for object or type names.  However, no matter what you do, you need to remember that *all data in a given column of a result set must be of the same datatype*.

Most [Entity-Attribute-Value tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) like this sacrifice data integrity that strong typing brings by accepting that the data type is determined by the application and not the RDBMS.  EAV does not allow you to have your cake (store data without a fixed schema) and eat it, too (enjoy DB enforced strong data typing, not having to typecast strings in the application, etc.).

EAV breaks data normalization pretty badly.  It breaks First Normal Form; the most basic rule, and this is just one of the consequences.  EAV tables will make querying the data anywhere from awkward to extremely difficult, and you're almost always going to sacrifice performance doing it because the RDBMS is built around the relational model.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't ever use EAV tables.  They're relatively great for user defined fields.  However, it does mean that they're always going to suck to query and manage.  That's just the tradeoff.  You broke First Normal Form.  Querying and performance are going to suffer consequences of that choice.

If you really want to store your *all* your data like this, you should look at either storing data as blobs of XML or JSON (SQL Server 2016) -- but that's a general pain to query -- or use a NoSQL data store like MongoDB or Cassandra instead of an SQL RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks @Bacon Bits, that's given me several things to think further about - in particular whether it would be better to store the data as XML or JSON rather than sets of records in a child table, as I can see definite advantages to the XML/JSON approach. 

The query performance may or may not be an issue, and it's something I need to think carefully about - in one sense, I'm building a big data dump which may need specific transformation to be useful to client apps as part of their design; on the other, making the data directly usable would in most cases be obviously better